# Calculating small worldness for a network

Tags: matlab, graph, graph-theory

Suppose i am give data for a test network. (Huge data set). Something like this in a file.

1 2
1 3
1 4
1 5
1 6
1 7
1 8
1 9
1 10
1 11
...

How can i calculate small worldness for this test network?
Will i first have to form a graph of it and figure out its clustering coefficient and path length?

I am trying to understand this [journal](http://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0002051) but facing lot of problem.

Answer (score 1):

Small worldness means small avg. path distance with high clustering, both compared to random networks. There is a measure for quantifying it.

http://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0002051

x: You may calculate avg path length, divide it to avg path length of a random network with same node-edge count.

y: Then calculate avg clustering coefficient, divide it to avg clustering coefficient of a random network with same node-edge count.

Then calculate S=y/x.

If S>1 then the network can be labeled as "small world".

Comment: Random network to test, can be create using the generation with the Watts-Strogatz method [link](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.generators.random_graphs.watts_strogatz_graph.html#networkx.generators.random_graphs.watts_strogatz_graph)? Any example? thanks